# Unable to assign when TField::Validating property is true

Tags: c++builder, vcl

I have a weird situation where a straight assignment to a field in `TClientDataSet` results in `NULL` irrespective of what the value is. The code in question is below:

`cdsMain->FieldByName("CustomerID")->AsString = CustomerID;`

`CustomerID` is of the type `String`. When I inspected the `TField`, the only one that stood out was the readonly `Validating` property, which was `true`. However my `OnValidate` callback is `NULL` and so is other events associated with this `TField`. When I make the `Validating` property to `false` (in the debugger), I see the value that is assigned (with no code executing). When I inspect a 'working' field, it's `Validating` is false. Embarcadero has no information on this property in their help page. Any idea on what this property might be and why I am seeing this behavior? Thanks.

IDE: C++ RAD 10.1 Berlin
OS: Win 10